# Why is PDFBox deleting a rectangle line when converting to Image file

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

[broken converted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oY6W.png)
I try to convert a pdf to an image file.... it works fine, but it deletes a line in one of the rectangles.... I can't figure out why.....

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream(new File(".....pdf")));

    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
    List pages = docCatalog.getAllPages();

    for (Object pageObj : pages)
    {
        PDPage page = (PDPage) pageObj;
        BufferedImage pdfImage = page.convertToImage();
        ImageIO.write(pdfImage, "png", new File("/......png"));

    }
    doc.close();
}
```

Before I deleted all text of the pdf.... could it be that it is still hassling with one of the text width, which then overwrites the rectangles line ? 
Plse see pdf here...[image: origin PDF]

Comment: Please supply the PDF in question for inspection.

Comment: I just can add images no pdf... so I added the pdf as an image...guess it won't help as u can t inspect it...

Comment: You are right, inspection only is relevant when applied to the PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to reproduce the problem, it turned out that the current PDFBox 1.7.1 properly renders the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mCnU.png). The problem only occurred when using the old version 0.7.3.

Thus, if using Maven, use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

or a newer version of this dependency in case of such trouble.